# KDE does not remember autostart settings

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 17.04, autostart, guake

KDE Plasma 5.9 (Xubuntu 17.04 with Kubuntu-Desktop installed) forgets the autostart settings as soon as I close the autostart dialog box. I'm trying to make Guake start with the system but the option does not stay enabled. Also, I had disabled screenlets and that was also forgotten. The only solution was to remove them.

I tried starting a new session to no avail. This is driving me insane. It worked fine with XFCE and still seems to work.